# Firefox: blur event triggering only on second click outside the selected element any way to fix it?

Tags: jquery, firefox

Use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZLDa/2/) from one of my earlier questions for an example. It's quite problematic for many of my design choices.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('focused');
    }).on('blur', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
    })
});
```

code for those who can't get to jsfiddle for whatever reason.

Are there any known solutions or workaround to this?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: oh sorry, got ahead of myself a bit. Just looking for a workaround or solution.

Comment: Okay, what are you trying to achieve? When I click the select box, the  container div goes grey. Then I make a selection and it turns white again. Is this not correct?

Comment: then try clicking outside of it, it should also turn white. Except it only does it on the second click outside of it when using firefox.

Comment: Looks like this is just a browser issue... When I open ur fiddle up in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/WZLDa/2/ I don't have this issue like I do in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I keep messing with this but it appears to be just an issue with the way Firefox handles clicking off a select element since im not getting this issue in Chrome or IE... and in Safari it doesn't even register the click until the second time you click on it.